# No I don't want to take your survey

Tags: bug, design, user-experience

New banner on the main stackoverflow site has an X button on it.  Click it, it goes away.  Navigate to another page, the banner is back....

Can you please make it so that stops showing up if I click X?

Screenshot as per request from comments.

[image]

Comment: Are you browsing in private mode or in a browser with tracking/cookies blocked, by any chance?

Comment: Cookies are not blocked, but I have them set to delete when the browser closes.  Is this a cookie issue?  Edit: Tracking is blocked though.

Comment: I would imagine whether the banner is shown after being closed is almost definitely powered by cookies. If you're not closing the browser before going to another page, though, then at least something else is at play.

Comment: Not closing the window.  I can definitely try enabling tracking though to see if anything changes.

Comment: Changed the privacy settings back to standard and unchecked the deletion of cookies on close.  Behaviour did not change.  Also tried using Edge, which I don't believe has my privacy settings in it (rarely use it), and the behaviour was consistent there as well.

Comment: Short term, I'll probably just add a snippet to my userscript for the site to remove the banner, but it's just annoying.

Comment: You might want to open your developer console and capture both traffic, cookies and local storage. The earlier bug report was status-completed but got reverted back to status-planned. Lack of reproducible bug reports I guess made it stalled.